# PostgreSQL and SELECT FOR UPDATE LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking

Can you please explain me this strange behaviour:

I have this stored procedure which tell me if a row is locked

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tg_availablega_is_unlocked(availablega_id integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  is_locked     boolean = FALSE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    PERFORM id FROM tg_availablega WHERE id = availablega_id
    FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN lock_not_available THEN
            is_locked := TRUE;
  END;
  RETURN not is_locked;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

If I start a transaction and execute this:

```
SELECT "tg_availablega"."id",
       "tg_availablega"."isactive",
       "tg_availablega"."schedule",
       "tg_availablega"."zone_tg_id"
FROM "tg_availablega"
WHERE (tg_availablega_is_unlocked("tg_availablega"."id")
       AND "tg_availablega"."zone_tg_id" = 1
       AND "tg_availablega"."isactive" = TRUE
       AND "tg_availablega"."schedule" = 20)
LIMIT 100
FOR
UPDATE;
```

It locks and return 100 rows. If I execute the same simultaneously in other transaction, it locks and return different 100 rows. If rows total are 101 then first executuon return 100 rows and second execution return just 1 remaining row.

BUT if I add ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT "tg_availablega"."id",
       "tg_availablega"."isactive",
       "tg_availablega"."schedule",
       "tg_availablega"."zone_tg_id"
FROM "tg_availablega"
WHERE (tg_availablega_is_unlocked("tg_availablega"."id")
       AND "tg_availablega"."zone_tg_id" = 1
       AND "tg_availablega"."isactive" = TRUE
       AND "tg_availablega"."schedule" = 20)
***ORDER BY "tg_availablega"."id"***
LIMIT 100
FOR
UPDATE;
```

then the first transaction return 100 locked rows, and second transaction return NO ROWS

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function tg_availablega_is_unlocked does lock the rows it examines. Without order by, Postgres doesn't visit all rows - so the function doesn't get called on all of them. I think You meant:

```
select * from (
SELECT "tg_availablega"."id",
   "tg_availablega"."isactive",
   "tg_availablega"."schedule",
   "tg_availablega"."zone_tg_id"
FROM "tg_availablega"
 WHERE "tg_availablega"."zone_tg_id" = 1
   AND "tg_availablega"."isactive" = TRUE
   AND "tg_availablega"."schedule" = 20)
ORDER BY "tg_availablega"."id"
) a
where tg_availablega_is_unlocked(id)
limit 100
```